# PhpMyAdmin não abre após mudança de sena padrão

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin, xampp

Boa tarde pessoal,

Após modificar a senha padrão do Mysql (Na interface do Xampp), ele não abre mais e exibe a seguinte mensagem de erro:

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

" O phpMyAdmin tentou ligar-se ao servidor MySQL, e o servidor rejeitou a ligação. Verifique o anfitrião, nome de utilizador e palavra-passe no config.inc.php e assegure-se que correspondem à informação fornecida pelo administrador do MySQL. "

Fiz as seguintes modificações no config.inc.php, sem sucesso:

/* Authentication type and info */;

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'NOVA-SENHA';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

$cfg['Lang'] = '';

Depois disso, fiz uma cópia de config.inc.php

Renomeei o config.sample.inc.php para config.inc.php;

Ao digitar localhost/phpmyadmin, é exibido um wizard de configuração do mysql e ele não passa da primeira página. Então retornei ao estado anterior;

Tentei resetar a senha de root utilizando um bat já existente na instalação do xampp (resetaroot.bat), e o retorno foi o seguinte:

c:\xampp\mysql>resetroot.bat

**[Warning]** TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --ex
plicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).

**[Note]** Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

**[Note]** InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages

**[Note]** InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

**[Note]** InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

**[Note]** InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3

**[Note]** InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions

**[Note]** InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M

**[Note]** InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

**[ERROR]** InnoDB: .\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode

**[ERROR]** InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!

**[ERROR]** Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.

**[ERROR]** Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

**[ERROR]** Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB

**[ERROR]** Aborting

**[Note]** Binlog end

**[Note]** bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

Passwoerter fuer Benutzer "root" und "pma" wurden geloescht.

Passwords for user "root" and "pma" were deleted.

Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .

Modifiquei a senha do mysql pela própria interface do xammp, porém é exibida a mesma mensagem de erro:

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

" O phpMyAdmin tentou ligar-se ao servidor MySQL, e o servidor rejeitou a ligação. Verifique o anfitrião, nome de utilizador e palavra-passe no config.inc.php e assegure-se que correspondem à informação fornecida pelo administrador do MySQL. "

**Outra informação:** O MySql não aparece como serviço em services.msc;

Desde já agradeço o apoio de todos.

Comment: Niltão!!!! como está rapaz blz meu irmão? quanto tempo rapaz! hahaha. Voltou pra Fortal? Meu chapa seu problema parece ser permissão no diretório do Mysql. Um abração cara!

Comment: Confere aqui também: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907736/change-mysql-root-password-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: Faaaaala Gustavão! Beleza meu brother? Quanto tempo meu irmão! Voltei, estou morando em Jericoacoara! Interessante que a poucos dias antes de postar esta pergunta, fui ao teu perfil no facebook mas parece que você não acessa muito lá...hahaha..Agora sei qual a rede social você costuma interagir! hehehe..Pois é, modifiquei a senha padrão do mysql pela interface do xampp e parece que deu divergência de configuração, não atualizando a senha em todos os arquivos. Daí tive que deixar assim: mysql_safe -skip-grant-tables -skip-network & pra fazer o backup dos bancos. valeu pelo apoio! Abração!

Comment: voce tem que modificar a senha no config.inc.php também manualmente ou excluir o arquivo e acessar o setup do phpmyadmin para criar um com novas configurações! o arquivo config.sample.inc.php é uma amostra de como deve ser! você não deve alterá-lo manualmente!!!